# r subset columns based on matching pattern sequence

Tags: r, subset

Looks like this question has been asked many times. I cannot find a solution that matches with what I am looking for.

I have a dataset with many columns, atleast 100 columns.  Most of the columns repeat with the same column name, the last string varies. Something like this

```
   Id Date        ABC_XYZ_1  ABC_XYZ_2   ABC_XYZ_3   ABC_XYZ_4..........ABC_XYZ_65    ABC_XYZ_DT ABC_XYZ_BY
   1  10/11/2021  1          1           3           -8       ..........3            12/11/2021   Joe Brown
   2  08/12/2002  4          2           4           -6       ..........4            07/14/2021   Bailey Ron
```

I am only interested in 65 columns starting with `ABC_XYZ_1`  `ABC_XYZ_2`  `ABC_XYZ_3`...ending in `ABC_XYZ_65`.

Expected output, a dataset with 65 columns like this

```
ABC_XYZ_1  ABC_XYZ_2   ABC_XYZ_3   ABC_XYZ_4..........ABC_XYZ_65
1          1           3           -8       ..........3
4          2           4           -6       ..........4
```

I know I can use something `df[, c(ABC_XYZ_1 , ABC_XYZ_2, ABC_XYZ_3......ABC_XYZ_65)]` but I am not interesting in copying the column names `ABC_XYZ_1`  `ABC_XYZ_2`  `ABC_XYZ_3`......`ABC_XYZ_65` 65 times. Any suggestions for an efficient way to accomplish this is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `df %>% select(contains('ABC'))` using `dplyr`

Comment: @RonakShah, If i use your solution I will get all the columns including , columns `ABC_XYZ_DT ABC_XYZ_BY`, I dont want that. only columns `ABC_XYZ_1 ABC_XYZ_2 ABC_XYZ_3.....ending in ABC_XYZ_65`

Comment: @bison2178 You can do `df %>% select(matches("^ABC_XYZ_\\d+$"))` or another option is `df[, paste0("ABC_XYZ_", 1:65)]`

Comment: @akrun, that worked. If you post this as a solution. I will accept it.